# Message: Undefined variable error in CodeIgniter when passing data to view

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch data from database into an array and then display the information but I am getting the following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Undefined variable $result
> Filename: views/timeline.php
>
> Line Number: 53
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aswp\application\views\timeline.php
> Line: 53
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aswp\application\controllers\Home.php
> Line: 14
> Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aswp\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

This is my Controller function

```
public function displayDiscussion()
    {
        $data['result'] = $this->discussions->displayDisc();
        $this->load->view('timeline',$data);
    
        
    }
```

Model

```
function displayDisc()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT title, content, username, dateTime FROM discussions;");
    return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?> 
    <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->content; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->dateTime; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where/when is `$result` set?

Comment: What does $data['result'] print ??

Answer (score 0):

debuge data in controller using

```
public function displayDiscussion()
    {
        $data['result'] = $this->discussions->displayDisc();
        print_r($data);exit;

        $this->load->view('timeline',$data);
    
        
    }
```